# how to get memory usage of a java process using SIGAR library?

Tags: java, sigar

The process below is executing a c++ code.I want to know the memory used by the c++ code.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("./" + compiledFile);
Process pp = p.start();
long id = getProcessID(pp);
Sigar sigar=new Sigar();
ProcMem memory=new ProcMem();
memory.gather(sigar, id);
System.out.println("memory ---> "+Long.toString(memory.getSize()));
```

I have tried the follwing code.But it returns sigar exception: "No such process".
To get the process id I am using following method

```
public long getProcessID(Process p)
    {
        long pid = -1;
        try
        {
            if (p.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) 
            {
                Field f = p.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                result = f.getLong(p);
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            pid = -1;
        }
        return pid;
    }
```

I am a novice.Did I get something wrong? Or Am i doing something wrong?
any help or suggestion will be much appreciated..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this class](https://gist.github.com/shoestring/4200649). It is not *elegant* at all, but seems to be an example of what you would want to do.